# how to get the output of a function when the input is a list

Tags: python, arrays, function, evaluation

Imagine I have a function like below:

```
f = (s**2 + 2*s + 5) + 1
```

where s is :

```
s = [1 , 2 , 3]
```

How can I pass the s to my function?

I know that I can define a function like below:

```
def model(s):
    model = 1 + (s**2 + 2*s + 5)
    return model
fitted_2_dis = [model(value) for value in s]

print ("fitted_2_dis =", fitted_2_dis)
```

To get :

```
fitted_2_dis = [9, 14, 21]
```

I prefer to not using this method. Because my actual function is so big with a lot of expressions. So, instead of bringing all the expressions in my code, I defined my function like below:

```
sum_f = sum (f)

Sum_f in my code is the summation of bunches of expressions.
```

Is there any other way to evaluate my function (sum_f) when the input is an array?
Thanks

Comment: "So, instead of bringing all the expressions in my code, I defined my function like below" - that doesn't look like you defined a function at all.

Comment: @user2357112 the sum_f is the summation of some expressions in term of s

Answer (score 2):

The list comprehension method is a great method. Additionally you may also use `map`:

```
fitted_2_dis = list(map(model, s))
```

If you're a `numpy` fan you can use `np.vectorize`:

```
np.vectorize(model)(s)
```

Finally if you convert your array to `numpy`'s `ndarray` you an pass it in directly:

```
import numpy as np

s = np.array(s)
model(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Map](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#map) function will fulfill the task quite nicely:

```
>>> map(model, s)
[9, 14, 21]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import numpy as np


def sum_array(f):
    np_s = np.array(f)
    return (np_s**2 + 2*np_s + 5) + 1

s = [1, 2, 3]
sum_f = sum_array(s)
```